# Angular-daterangepicker view not getting $scope StarDate and Endate

Tags: angularjs, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I'm getting a problem with angular-daterangepicker, when trying to pass my model data to the view.

```
 $scope.date = {startDate: resolvedItems.start_date, endDate: resolvedItems.end_date};
```

Doing a `console.log($scope.date)` returns `{startDate: "2006-08-20 05:11:32", endDate: "2009-10-18 23:03:06"}`

But in the view I get the today daterange (2016-06-29 00:00:00 - 2016-06-29 23:59:59).

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>
         {{"scale.form.startAndEndDate" | translate}}
      </label>
         <input date-range-picker class="form-control date-picker reportrange" type="text" ng-model="date" />
  </div>
```

What possibly I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've solved my problem using the options attribute:

Model:

```
$scope.dateRangePickerOptions = {
         startDate: resolvedItems.start_date,
         endDate: resolvedItems.end_date
 }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>
         {{"scale.form.startAndEndDate" | translate}}
      </label>
         <input date-range-picker class="form-control date-picker reportrange" type="text" ng-model="date" options="dateRangePickerOptions"/>
  </div>
```